# How to assign edit rights but not delete rights in to a user in Testlink

Tags: testing, automation, testlink

As a admin of testlink I want to assign edit/update rights of test cases to a user but not give delete right, how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with Testlink.

There is a single permission called `mgt_modify_tc` that handles `create,edit,delete,order, move, and copy components, categories, and test cases` (as described in the [documentation](http://testlink.sourceforge.net/docs/documents/end-users/manual.html#d0e264))